# A $p$-group that is divisible.

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

> Suppose $G$ is an infinite $p$-group and $H$ is a minimal infinite subgroup of $G$ (where $p$ is a given prime). If $H=pH$ then $H$ is divisible.

How can this be? An element of $H$ will only be divisible by a power of $p$, am I right?

EDIT: I've been able to prove any $y\in H$ is divisible by $n$ if $(n,p)=1$ or $n=p^r$ but I fail if $n=tp^s$ with $(t,p)=1$.

Comment: No you are not right. An element of of order $m$ has an $n$-th roots for any $n$ that is coprime to $m$.

Comment: I had the same confusion at @stf91 for some minutes... until I realized that in any cyclic group of order $p^k$, the homomorphism $g\to g^n$ is an _automorphism_ for $n$ prime to $p$... so the only salient issue is about $p$-divisibility.

Comment: The definition of p-group you gave is exactly that which I used in the question (original post).

Comment: @D.Holt: Now I see. I can write sm+tn=1 for some s,t in Z. Let |y|=m. Then y = smy + tny= 0 + n(ty). Let y in H (see O.P.). Then |y| = p^r. If n is a positive integer, then either (n,p) = 1 or p|n. If the former then I showed y has an n-th root. If n = p then by the equality H = pH, y is divisible by n. But what if n = tp for some t > 1?

Comment: I HAVE edited the OP adding extra data.

Comment: In the general case, first find a $t$-th root and then find a $p^s$-th root of that.

Comment: I already did that. I returned to the problem with a fresh head an immediately found a solution. Thank you very much anyways.

Answer (score 1):

How silly I am! Just before reading Derek's last comment I found a complete proof. Let $y\in H$ and $n=tp^s$, with $(t,p)=1$. By the O.P. there is $x\in H$ such that $y=tx$. By the O.P. again there is $z\in H$ such that $x=p^s z$. So $y=t(p^s z)=(tp^s)z=nz$. I can't believe such an innocent statement as $H$ $p$-group and $H=pH$ gives $H$ divisible.

EDIT: Ahhh, in the hypothesis (see O.P.) all that matters is that $G$ is a $p$-group. The other assumptions can be dropped.

By the way, if $G$ is any group, $y\in G$ and $m,n$ divide $y$ then $y$ is divisible by $mn$ as suggested above.